# Ignoring Collisions Between Bodies in Box2d (iphone)

Tags: iphone, filter, box2d, collision-detection, collision

I have 3 types of bodies. they are

1) MouseJointBody (It is moving with mouseJoint only)

2) 2 MovingBodys (It is moving continuously in the world)

3) StaticBody (It is fixed in constant position)

I need collision between these bodies:

1) MouseJointBody with MovingBodys and StaticBody and world bounderies

2) StaticBody only with MouseJointBody

3) MovingBodys only with MouseJointBody and world bounderies

4) MovingBodys collide with each other

but don't need collide with StaticBody and MovingBody. I set filter data for these bodies like below code:

StaticBody:

```
fixDef.filter.categoryBits=0x0004;
fixDef.filter.maskBits= 0x0002;
```

MovingBodys:

```
fixDef.filter.categoryBits=0x0004;
fixDef.filter.maskBits= 0x0002;
```

MouseJointBody:

```
fixDef.filter.categoryBits=0x0002;
fixDef.filter.maskBits= 0x0004;
```

Everything working fine but my MovingBodys are not collide with eachother and  MouseJointBody and MovingBody not collide with the world box. these two are going out of the world. please tell me the solution for this one.

Comment: This might help: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering

Answer (score 0):

In Farseer that is a proyect baseb in Box2D exist CollisionCategory but in Box2D to resolve different

please, review the follow [discussion](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=197)

the idea is to assign that body type is each, and that bodies can collide only.

in the discussiontreated a similar case, A hits B, C hits D, but A does not hits A

Answer (score 0):

I think, when you use filters, you need apply filters to walls.
And set maskBits of all.

MovingBodys exemple :

```
fixDef.filter.categoryBits=0x0004;
fixDef.filter.maskBits= 0x0002 | 0x0006;
```

(0x0006 is the categoryBits of wall)